# RabbitMQ -- Unable to Execute Commands due to "libtinfo.so.6" error

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, debian, upgrade

In attempting to upgrade a RabbitMQ node on Debian Stretch from 3.8.3 to 3.8.6, I've attempted the three methods in [their documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) of Package Cloud, Bintray, and manual installation via dpkg. None of them worked, and I'm now unable to start or stop the rabbitmq-server (although I'm still able to access the management client on port :15672.). When trying to run any Rabbit command, the following output is presented:

```
bitnami@Admin-RabbitMQ-01:~$ sudo rabbitmq-server -detached
/usr/lib/erlang/erts-11.0.3/bin/beam.smp: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file "beam.smp" is in its given directory, but I'm unsure of what to do about libtinfo.so.6.

[Directory Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtdJz.png)

I'm using Erlang 22, for further clarification. Any help or advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `libtinfo.so.6` is provided by the package `libtinfo6`, which only exists in Debian Buster, not in Stretch. Make sure you download and install the Erlang binary package for the right Debian version.

Comment: Thank you! I uninstalled erlang following [this guide](https://howtoinstall.co/en/debian/jessie/erlang?action=remove) and RabbitMQ following [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185691/rabbitmq-installation-error), and following a reinstall of both, the libtinfo6 error is gone, and a new error now occurs stating that it has failed to create the .erlang.cookie file, which is likely a separate issue. I appreciate your help, Legoscia!!

Comment: Glad to hear! Problems with .erlang.cookie files are usually about file permissions, the HOME environment variable, or both. There are a few questions here on stack overflow that might help.

Comment: Good to know; I'll look into both of those options for the cookie configuration. Thank you again!